# Zend Framework - Form Description - Disable Escape?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Is it possible to disable the escaping that is performed on the Zend_Form setDescription method?

For example, in my controller, i'm testing if a login is successful, and if not setting the description (a H2) to the title plus an error message:

```
$form->setDescription('Login: <span class="error">Invalid Details</span>');
```

The above works, but replaces the `<` and `>` characters with their appropriate converted value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer myself!

```
$form->setDescription('Login: <span class="error">Invalid Details</span>');
$form->getDecorator('Description')->setEscape(false);
```